# Finding all or none

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables detailing an amusement park and its guests' ride history.

```
   Categories
  c_id    name
  1    Thrill
  2    Leisure
  3    Kiddie

    Rides 
 r_id  c_id 
  1     1
  2     1
  3     2
  4     2
  5     3
  6     3

guest_history
h_id   g_id
 1      1
 2      1
 3      2
 4      3

history_items
 h_id  r_id
  1     5
  2     6
  3     1
  3     2
  4     5
```

How would I get all of the guests (g_id's) that have either rode all of the kiddie rides or none of the kiddie rides?

Expected Output would be:

```
g_id
 1
 2
```

I can't seem to figure out what the easiest way to go about it would be. I can only seem to conjure up a table that contains all of the cases that a guest has rode a kiddie ride. My attempt was a 4-way inner join of the tables and to filter out on the c_id = "Kiddie". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After your join, where c_id = 3 and grouped by g_id, you have `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 OR COUNT(*) = 0`.

Comment: You cannot do this with those four tables.  You need another table with just `guests` to get guests who have ridden NO rides, which would meet your conditions.

Comment: Say we wanted all of the guests that rode all of the rides of every category and all of the guests that rode at least one ride in each category, would this be a trivial change? How would we factor in each category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this below logic-

> 3 is fixed in the query to get category "Kiddie"

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e33b0324d0b742f2d327885d7b2de69a)

```
SELECT A.g_id,COUNT(C.r_id)
FROM guest_history A
INNER JOIN history_items B ON A.h_id = B.h_id
INNER JOIN Rides C ON B.r_id = C.r_id AND C.c_id = 3
GROUP BY A.g_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.r_id) = (SELECT COUNT(r_id) FROM Rides WHERE c_id = 3)
OR COUNT(DISTINCT B.r_id) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT g_id
FROM Categories
NATURAL JOIN Rides
NATURAL JOIN guest_history
NATURAL JOIN history_items
GROUP BY g_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r_id) IN (0,
                                (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r_id)
                                 FROM Categories
                                 NATURAL JOIN Rides
                                 WHERE name = 'Kiddie')
                               )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=999b33f809d735347941721b0e2a6079)